# TypeError in __init__() unable to solve

Tags: python, class, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


class window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        box=Frame(self).pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        login=Frame(box,self).pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        register=Frame(box,self).pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

        self.fup(login)

    def fup(self,f):
        f.tkraise()

class login(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller,**kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        lab=Label(self,text='Login').grid(row=0,column=3,pady=3)
        but=Button(self,text='Signup',command=lambda : controller.fup(register)).grid(row=4,column=0)

class register(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller,**kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        lab=Label(self,text='Register').grid(row=0,column=3,pady=3)
        but=Button(self,text='<<',command=lambda : controller.fup(login)).grid(row=0,column=0)



win=window()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What went wrong? Is there a traceback? If so, post it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*. You should also consider the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Are all the widgets in this layout relevant to the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems here.  First, you're confused about how classes and class objects work.  When you said

```
        login=Frame(box,self).pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
```

That does not create an object of class `login`.  It creates a simple Frame.  In this case, it doesn't store an object at all, because the `pack` method does not return anything.  In your `login` class, you refer to `register`, but that isn't an object, it's a class.

This is closer to what you want, and brings up a window, but since I can't tell what you really wanted, you'll have to take it from here.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class login(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        lab=Label(self,text='Login').grid(row=0,column=3,pady=3)
        but=Button(self,text='Signup',command=lambda : controller.fup(controller.register)).grid(row=4,column=0)

class register(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        lab=Label(self,text='Register').grid(row=0,column=3,pady=3)
        but=Button(self,text='<<',command=lambda : controller.fup(controller.login)).grid(row=0,column=0)


class window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        box=Frame(self) 
        box.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        self.login=login(box,self) 
        self.login.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        self.register=register(box,self) 
        self.register.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

        self.fup(self.login)

    def fup(self,f):
        f.tkraise()

win=window()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks a lot .. but i'm not enough clear about class ... any website to get clarified